# Reduce Observable<T[]> into T[]

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs, angular2-observables

If I'm working with an `Observable<number[]>` and I would like to collect all the emissions into a single `number[]` .

I have always done something like this:

```
const items$ = Rx.Observable.of([10, 20, 30], [20,30,40])
  .reduce((acc, curr) => acc.concat(curr));

let itemsArray = [];

items.subscribe(arr => itemsArray = arr);

console.log(itemsArray); // [10, 20, 30, 20, 30, 40]
```

I was just wondering if there is any way to "**collect**" items from an Observable - inline in RxJS without calling subscribe on the observable.

This would suggest a **synchronous** approach which I'm not sure is possible given the async nature of observables.

Something like:

```
const itemsArray = Rx.Observable.of([10, 20, 30], [20,30,40])
  .reduce((acc, curr) => acc.concat(curr))
  .collect( /* return a number[]  - not an Observable<number[]> */);


console.log(itemsArray); // [10, 20, 30, 20, 30, 40]
```

Comment: Are you looking for reduce operator? https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/reduce.md

Comment: You can't access the values of an observable without subscribing to it. Observable operators take streams and produce streams. The mechanism for taking a "snapshot", sometimes called "unwrapping the stream", is exactly `subscribe`. The title of your question would be better expressed as "**Unwrap** `Observable<T[]>` into `T[]`". 
In other words, what you are calling `collect` is in essence `subscribe`.

Comment: you need to subscribe to run the sequence, if you really don't want to subscribe, just use imperative programming, you can use the same methods with array, reduce() ,concat() etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do it without subscribing.
**It's a stream (cold) and you need to subscribe in order to receive values.**

That say, I think what do you want is to **not** wait until the last value has been emitted, and receive the new concatenated array over time (which is totally possible).

The operator to use for that is : **[scan](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-scan)**.
*in fact, you weren't far with reduce ;) !!*

```
const items$ = Rx
  .Observable
  .of([10, 20, 30], [20,30,40])
  .scan((acc, curr) => acc.concat(curr), []);


items$.subscribe(arr => console.log(arr));
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/2e8eR6RrHrrE1WOuRRdf?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

+1 to Maxime's answer.

For the completeness, if the `Observable` is a [`ScalarObservable`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/observable/ScalarObservable.ts), you may reach for the `value` property.

But that's not part of the documented API so it's not a good thing to do, considering maintainability.